# simple print statement is not working inside method with if statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started learning Python code recently and one simple print statement is giving me trouble since last 4 days.

**Problem:** the print statement is not working inside the `validatePostcode(postcode)` method for if-statement. The assigned value is 200 (status code) which is printing fine without the if-statement. Also, when I compare with the True (result value) for that API it works fine without if-statement, why it is not working after I apply the if and try to compare?

**Error:**

```
  File "./py_script3.py", line 32
    print ("Congrats")
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

---

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3


    import os,re,sys


    import urllib.request as req
    import json

    def loadJsonResponse(url):
        #return json.loads(req.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8'))['result']
        #return json.loads(req.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8'))['status']
        print ("I am in loadJsonResponse before returning string")
        string = json.loads(req.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8'))
        return string
        print ("I am in loadJsonResponse after returning string")

    def lookuppostcode(postcode):
        url = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/{}'.format(postcode)
        return loadJsonResponse(url)

    def validatePostcode(postcode):
        url = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/{}/validate'.format(postcode)
        #return loadJsonResponse(url)
        string = json.loads(req.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8'))
        Value = str(string['status'])
        print (Value)
        if Value == 200 :
        print ("Congrats")

    def randomPostcode():
        url = 'https://api.postcodes.io/random/postcodes'
        return loadJsonResponse(url)

    def queryPostcode(postcode):
        url = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes?q={}'.format(postcode)
        return loadJsonResponse(url)

    def getAutoCompletePostcode(postcode):
        url = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/{}/autocomplete'.format(postcode)
        return loadJsonResponse(url)

    #Input = input("Enter the postcode : ")
    #print(lookuppostcode('CB3 0FA'))
    validatePostcode('CB3 0FA')
    #print(queryPostcode('HU88BT'))
    #print(randomPostcode(Input))
```

Comment: After a line with `if...:` an indented block with code to execute conditionally is expected.

Comment: I added a line in between my if statement and print statement, but does not work, is that what you suggested Michael ?

Comment: Can I have an example pleasE?

Comment: Adding a line doesn't work. If you are not familiar enough with Python you should start with the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: Well Sure, as I said I recently started, I am learning on the fly. I just needed and example to add the indented block after if statement. Anyways thanks Michael

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This piece of code (which is generating the error):

```
if Value == 200 : 
print ("Congrats")
```

Should be

```
if Value == 200 : 
    print ("Congrats")
```

Because python expects an indented block after the conditional, just like the message error is saying to you

Comment: Great , I am not getting the error of indented block now, but its not printing the "Congrats"

Comment: You have sure that the `Value` is `200`?

Comment: figured out why not working...the if was not able to compare the numeric value as string. I am good with my script Thanks so much Mr Tacon.

Comment: You can use `int(Value)` to cast it to an integer

Answer (score 0):

You should indent the print statement like so:

```
if Value == 200 :
   print ("Congrats")
```

You can read more about this [here](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/ifstatements.html)!

Answer (score -1):

From https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html:

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in turn is used to determine the grouping of statements.

By doing

```
if Value == 200:
print ("Congrats")
```

Python interprets the two lines as two different groups of statements. What you should do is:

```
if Value == 200:
    print ("Congrats")
```

Answer (score -1):

Need to add an indent after the if statement. You can do so by pressing return after typing the colon

Answer (score -1):

After the if-statement, a section of code to run when the condition is True is included. The section of  must be indented and every line in this section of code must be indented the same number of spaces. By convention, four space indentation is used in Python.

```
if Value == 200:
    print ("Congrats")
```